# How to ignore recursive cache data to fully get them on the database storage?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

On my DBMS, I have two tables having one-to-many relationship (A <- B).
At the first running, I retrieved some records of A (including B) like this:

```
var lst = from a in ctx.As.Include("Bs") select a;
```

So, everything is ok.
But a few minutes later, I want to get them again because they could be changed on other apps.

I tried to use

```
ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, lst);
```

When I do that, the only things are refreshed is object from B, not A.
Therefore, I must do another step like:

```
foreach (var a in lst) {
    ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, a.Bs);
}
```

It's also ok if I didn't include `Bs` in the linq statement, then use `Load` method instead of `Refresh`

The problem here is calling `Refresh` or `Load` too many times maybe decrease the performance. How can I re-load them from the database storage without so many calling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a few minutes later ...

Context is unit of work and unit of work usually doesn't take few minutes so the basic answer for your question is create new context and execute the query again.

If you really think that your context must live so long (I doubt that it must because in such case you would not want to overwrite local changes) you can try this:

```
ctx.As.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
ctx.Bs.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var lst = from a in ctx.As.Include("Bs") select a;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! In addition, I want to keep the context so I can save some change of instances into database. Because if I use another context, it will throw an exception. Sorry for my stupidity, I am a new bie in Entity Framework!